# How to switch Command and Control on JetBrains Rider?

Tags: rider

I'm coming from the Windows development world where I'm very used to a windows layout keyboard and Visual Studio commands.

I'm using a Macbook with JetBrains rider.  In the Operating System I have switched the Command and Control modifier keys.  Now, system wide I can use control + c, control + v, etc- as you would expect.

In JetBrains Rider, I have applied the Visual Studio 2022 keyboard scheme... however, I am noticing that they are now requiring me to press the command key instead of the control key (you know, the one I swapped).  Is there a way to change Jetbrains Rider such that I can have a Windows keyboard experience with Visual Studio hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 'Settings' in Rider

   - [menu bar - JetBrains Rider > Settings] or `⌘,`
2. Select the 'Keymap' option
3. Choose the 'Visual Studio' option and **Save**

   - To verify, I entered 'Copy' in the search bar and confirmed I was seeing the `^C` character rather than `⌘C`